# HSTS Preload Submission

Tags: .htaccess, hsts

I want to pass all tests for HSTS Preload.

I currently have 2 errors, that I need to solve:

**First:**

```
`http://example.com` (HTTP) should immediately redirect to
`https://example.com` (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain. 
Right now, the first redirect is to `https://www.example.com/`.
```

My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

**Second:**

```
Response error: No HSTS header is present on the response.
```

My htaccess looks like this:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=84600; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing and how can I pass the tests?

I use this test site; https://hstspreload.appspot.com/

Comment: The site you linked contains information about what the header should look like...

Comment: Also look up how to set up your redirects in apache. Which has been answered at least 1000 times here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"   
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not redirect the url http://domain.com/page to https://www.domain.com/page. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to pass the test.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,E=HTTPS:1]
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```